# How to access instance variable dynamically based on params[:controller]?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've got a partial which should access the instance variables of various Controllers based on the `params[:controller]` variable. Using `singularize` and `downcase`, I define the name of the instance variable, which is the singular of the controller name by convention.

But I only get a `String`. How can I call the instance variable which is named like the string?

For example I have the controller `Articles`, so I do the following:

```
params[:controller].singularize.downcase # => "article"
```

now I want to access `@article`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a `instance_variable_get()` method in ruby. So try something like this:

```
var_name = params[:controller].singularize.downcase # article
instance_variable_get("@#{var_name}")
```

P.S: remember that you should use `instance_variable_get` in the proper context.